# Intelligently enabling django.jQery everywhere in Django admin site

Tags: python, django, django-admin

The problem is, that in base templates of `django.contrib.admin` application, there is no `jQuery` and `django.jQuery` defined, they are appears only on several descendant templates. And I want to enable it everywhere because I want to add one JS-applet an all pages of admin-site. 
Of course it is possible to add needed scripts to overriden base template, BUT - in that cases when those several descendant templates inserts `jQuery` scripts after my ones - my applet will being reset.

My current solution is add script with applet in footer after all scripts, so its loading after all scripts loaded. And even if `jQuery` being loaded several times - it does not harm to my applet.
But I still feel, that I want to find even better solution, with which `jQuery` initialization will not be duplicated in all cases.
So maybe some knows if there any elegant solutions to add jQuery on all pages of django-admin?

ps
Applet which I want to set up is [django_bfm](https://github.com/nagisa/django-bfm). By default it works only on chosen models, and I want to make it appears everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine admin base template to look like this:

```
... some lines before...
<script type="text/javascript">window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "{% filter escapejs %}{% static "admin/" %}{% endfilter %}";</script>
{% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}
<INCLUDE YOUR JQUERY HERE>
{% block blockbots %}<meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" />{% endblock %}
... all other lines ...
```

In this case, you include the jquery you want and, as it is included always after the default admin scripts, admin site is going to be using the jquery you included...

Hope it helps!